# My app crashes when an EditText is empty and I press a button

Tags: java, android

Why when I click the button and nothing is written in EditText, the program crashes?

The app is used to calculate the load securing.Users enter values ​​and get the number of straps they need.But when a field is free, the app crashes

Code:

```
public class Ladungssicherung extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


    EditText stfinput;
    EditText gewichtinput;
    EditText winkelinput;

    String text;
    double k = 1.5;
    int cZ = 1; // beschleunigungsbeiwert nach unten
    double cX = 0.8; // beschleunigungsbeiwert nach vorne


    Dialog epicDialog;
    TextView unicode, ergebnissFeld;
    ImageView muinfoButton, closemuButton, infoalphaButton;

    @SuppressLint("StringFormatInvalid")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ladungssicherung);

        winkelinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.winkelInput);
        ergebnissFeld = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ergebniss);
        gewichtinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gewichtInput);
        stfinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.stfInput);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        text = sharedPreferences.getString("text", "");
        winkelinput.setText(text);
        sharedPreferences.edit().remove("text").commit();

        epicDialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);


        muinfoButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.infomuIcon);
        closemuButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.closemuinfo);
        infoalphaButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.infoalpha);

        muinfoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showmuinfo();


            }
        });

        infoalphaButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showalphawinkel();
            }
        });


        //Spinner code
        Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.numbers, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    }

    public void showalphawinkel() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WinkelmessActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }


    public void showmuinfo() {

        epicDialog.setContentView(R.layout.muinfo);
        closemuButton = (ImageView) epicDialog.findViewById(R.id.closemuinfo);

        closemuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                epicDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        epicDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        epicDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    public void ergebnissFromel(View v) {
        Spinner feld4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        Integer zahl1 = Integer.parseInt(gewichtinput.getText().toString());
        Integer zahl2 = Integer.parseInt(winkelinput.getText().toString());
        Integer zahl3 = Integer.parseInt(stfinput.getText().toString());

        String spinner = feld4.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Ladungssicherung">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/infoalpha"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/winkelInput"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/infomuIcon"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/info_icon" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="223dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView">

    </Spinner>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gewichtInput"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gewichtInput"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-108dp"
        android:text="Gewicht"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/gewichtInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="kg"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/winkelInput"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-211dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/spinner1"
        android:text="Winkel Alpha"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/winkelInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="211dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/alpha"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/stfInput"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:text="Vorspannkraft je Gurt"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/stfInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="daN"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gewicht" />


    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:background="@color/grau">

    </View>

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="277dp"
        android:background="@color/grau">

    </View>

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="275dp"
        android:background="@color/grau">

    </View>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:text="@string/mue"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-3dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView6"
        android:text="S"
        android:textSize="23sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/stfInput"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="TF"
        android:textSize="23sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/winkelInput"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="@string/alpha"
        android:textSize="23sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/infomuIcon"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/info_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titelNiederzurren"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
       android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:text="Niederzurren" />


    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="199dp"
        android:background="@color/grau">

    </View>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ergebniss"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
        android:background="@color/greensmiley"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonladungssicherung"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="ergebnissFromel"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post (with your question) your console output that occurs when your program crashes. And format your code so that the code is readable. Also, you have to include more details. Which edittext are you referring to when you say "nothing is written in EditText"? Show us where you initialize your edit text/buttons, and your XML. Right now, it is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these codes and let us get updated with what you see:

```
public void ergebnissFromel(View v) {

    Spinner feld4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    Integer zahl1 = 0;
    Integer zahl2 = 0;
    Integer zahl3 = 0;

    try
    {
        zahl1 = Integer.parseInt(gewichtinput.getText().toString());
        zahl2 = Integer.parseInt(winkelinput.getText().toString());
        zahl3 = Integer.parseInt(stfinput.getText().toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
    }

    String spinner = feld4.getSelectedItem().toString();


    if ( zahl1.equals("") || zahl1 == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bitte geben Sie das Gewicht an", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    if ( zahl2.equals("") || zahl2 == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bitte geben Sie das Gewicht an", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    if ( zahl3.equals("") || zahl3 == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bitte geben Sie das Gewicht an", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else {

        // Grad wird in sinus alpha umgerechnet
        double newsinus = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(Float.valueOf(zahl2)));

        double wert1 = cX - Float.valueOf(spinner) * cZ;
        double wert2 = Float.valueOf(spinner) * newsinus;

        // Formel Niederzurren Algorithmus
        double wert3 = wert1 * zahl1;
        double wert4 = wert2 * k;
        double wert5 = wert3 / wert4;
        double wert6 = Math.round(wert5);
        double wert7 = wert6 / zahl3;
        double wert8 = Math.ceil(wert7);

        ergebnissFeld.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(wert8)));

    }
}
```

Comment: if now a field remains free " For input string " " "

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting NumberFormatException because you are trying to **parse empty String to Integer**. Surround `Integer.parseInt(gewichtinput.getText().toString())` lines with **try catch** blocks, and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when your app crashes, you'll find a stack trace logged that will help you understand where the problem is.  You can find the log within Android Studio's Debug|Console tab.  Alternatively you can use the adb command from a terminal/shell window.  I like using "adb logcat -v time".

Comment: i get this from logcat:

Answer (score 0):

Before parsing to integer, you should check wether the input is null.
Furthermore, you're calling a method on zahl1 and check wether it is null afterwards.

```
String strZahl1 = gewichtinput.getText().toString(); //Get input as String
if(strZahl1 == null || strZahl1.isEmpty()) //First make sure that strZahl1 is not null, then check wether it is empty
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Bitte geben Sie das Gewicht an",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
Integer zahl1 = Integer.parseInt(strZahl1);
```

If the user is able to enter something else than a number into your textfields, you could surround the parsing with a try block:

```
 Integer zahl1;
 try
 {
    zahl1 = Integer.parseInt(strZahl1);
 }
 catch(NumberFormatException e)
 {
     Toast.makeText(this, strZahl1 + " ist keine gültige Zahl", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app crashes because .getText().toString is an empty string. Java cannot convert an empty string into an integer.

A better way is to do something like

```
Integer zahl1 ; 
if((gewichtinput.getText() != null) && (!gewichtinput.getText().toString.isEmpty()))
{
    zahl1 = Integer.parseInt(gewichtinput.getText().toString());
}
else
{
    zahl1 = 0 ; 
}
```

Do the same for all the other edit texts.
It should hopefully work